# Discord.js Collection - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, typeerror

Please forgive me as I am a super novice "coder" and relying heavily on ChatGPT to help. It has gotten me Excellent results so far, but for this one I am stumped.

The premise is: I have a Discord bot that auto-deletes messages that contain certain keywords, and then logs it to another channel. I have attached a "Restore Message" button to the message in the log channel to restore the original message (via a webhook message to appear as though it was sent from the original user) if it is deemed acceptable. I successfully got this working, but the one hiccup was I was able to get it working using the button interaction user's display name and avatar, but now trying to get the original sender's display name and avatar gives is giving me lot's of trouble.

index.js:

```
const { Client, Collection, IntentsBitField, Partials } = require("discord.js");
const WOK = require("wokcommands");
// more code

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
  // more code
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});

client.originalAuthors = new Collection(); // Initialize the collection

client.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Starting Bot...");
  console.log("Connecting to MongoDB...");
  
  await mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB.");
  // rest of code
```

msgDel.js:

```
        // Get author information from original message
        const originalAuthorInfo = { username: message.author.username, avatarURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() };
        client.originalAuthors.set(message.id, originalAuthorInfo);
        console.log("Added to originalAuthors map:", client.originalAuthors);
```

Because the original author's name and avatar URL successfully appear in the console log, I know this part is working.

interactionHandler.js:

```
const { InteractionType, ComponentType, fetch } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = async ( interaction, client ) => {
 // more code

 const originalAuthorInfo = client.originalAuthors.get(messageId);
 
 // more code

    switch (action) {
      case "restoreMessage":
        // Fetch the second part of the log message
        const logMessageRestore = logMessage;

        // Extract content and embeds from the log message
        const contentRestore = logMessageRestore.content
        const embedsRestore = logMessageRestore.embeds;
        const attachmentsRestore = Array.from(logMessageRestore.attachments.values()).map(att => att.url);
      
        // Fetch webhooks for the original channel
        let webhooks = await originalChannel.fetchWebhooks();
        let webhook = webhooks.first();
      
        // Create a webhook if none exists
        if (!webhook) {
          webhook = await originalChannel.createWebhook();
        }
        
        // Send the message back to the original channel using the webhook and append special character to restored messages
            content: originalContent,
            embeds: embedsRestore.map(embed => {
              if (embed.description) {
                embed.description += "᲼";
              }
              return embed;
            }),
            username: originalAuthorInfo.username,
            avatarURL: originalAuthorInfo.avatarURL,
            files: attachmentsRestore
          });
        }
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:
`Error handling the interaction: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') at module.exports (/home/container/events/interactionCreate/interactionHandler.js:33:53) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)`

interactionHandler.js:33 line 33 =  `const originalAuthorInfo = client.originalAuthors.get(messageId);`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried many different potential solutions (changing placement of initializing the collection in index.js, even more logging, and everything ChatGPT could think of... all of which has come back with no results.

Comment: try `const originalAuthorInfo = interaction.client.originalAuthors.get(messageId);`, and please tell me it worked or not.

Comment: @waki285 unfortunately not. And it returned a rather lengthy error in the console log that is apparently 8500+ characters too long to post in a comment.

Comment: You should put const originalAuthorInfo = client.originalAuthors.get(messageId); inside your case "restoreMessage" and make sure that the collection has the messageId stored. I think you are checking this function for many events that doesn't always store the message.